# Faster way to calculate the distance of each point to all other points in imported 3D point data

Tags: matlab, for-loop, euclidean-distance

I have 3D coordinate data of 221275 points. Also, I have an iterative process according to the values that I imported to MATLAB for each point. In this process, the average values of neighboring points near r<4 mm of each point are calculated. I wrote MATLAB code for this process, but the line " sqrt(sum((A - A(i1,:)).^2, 2)); " takes up a lot of the total time. I wrote down the process times for each line below. Is there a way I can run this code faster?

```
A = dlmread('E:\3D_point_data.txt');  % (221275 x 3) 
my_input = dlmread('E:\my_input.txt'); % (221275 x 1)
my_output = dlmread('E:\my_output.txt'); % (221275 x 1)
len1 = length(A);

par_new = zeros(len1,1);

for i1=1:len1
    
    C = sqrt(sum((A - A(i1,:)).^2, 2));  % 1006 seconds
    C(i1,1) = 1;                         % 
    ind = find(C<4);                     % 57 seconds
    mean_par = (mean(my_input(ind)))*2;  % 15 seconds

    par_new(i1) = my_input(i1,1) / mean_par;

end
    
par_new = par_new - my_output;
ind1 = find(par_new>0);
ind2 = find(par_new<0);
my_output(ind1) = my_output(ind1).*1.5;
my_output(ind2) = my_output(ind2)./1.5;
my_output(my_output>1)=1;
my_output(my_output<0.00001)=0.00001;
dlmwrite('E:\my_output.txt',my_output)
```

Comment: The obvious first step is to get rid of the sqrt( ) and compare to 16 instead of 4. To get rid of all of the temporary large arrays that also chew up time you may need to resort to a mex routine. Is the point data sorted in any way? Might be able to exploit that if it is.

Comment: Sort the points along one axis. For each point, with coordinate *c* along that axis, only calculate the (squared) distance for points with coordinates in the range (*c*,*c*+4).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Getting rid of sqrt reduced the process by 7-8% @James Tursa.

Comment: @beaker Could you please explain the sorting and "range (c,*c*+4)" part in more detail.

Comment: Sort the array A according to the values in, say, A(:,1) giving a new array S. For an example, let's say S(12,1) has the value 7.1. You only need to check the distances between S(12,:) and the rows that come *after* row 12, i.e. S(13,:), S(14,:), ..., until you reach a value in column 1 that is 11.1 or greater. If the distance along one axis is greater than your radius, the Euclidean distance between those points can never be less than the radius, so you can stop. Note that you never have to look *before* the current point because that will have already been checked.